# How to create variable after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a long format pandas dataframe that includes multiple entries for some people. I have a variable that indicates one measurements time since another separate assessment (assessment A). What I'd like to do is to create a new variable that identifies the time point of each assessment relative to assessment A, and assign each person's first time point (if it's <= 10 days of assessment A) as time point 1, then their subsequent measurements as 2, 3, 4 etc. regardless of time since assessment A. If they do not have an assessment <= 10 days of assessment A, then I'd like all entries for that person to be NA.

I'm sure the answer involves groupby. I am able to group by each persons code, but I'm quite stuck on how to proceed from there.

The logic I've been trying to follow is:
- groupby ID_Code
- for each ID_Code, test if first row 'time since assessment A' <= 10
- if true, first row = 1 in Timepoint AND assign that ID_Code's following rows 2, 3, 4 etc.
- else, assign all rows for that ID_Code as NA

I can provide more information if unclear. I'm quite new to cleaning my data with python and this is my first stackoverflow question so I'm open to any tips!

Thanks in advance.

```py
import pandas as pd

# Current data
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID_Code':['AA_01', 'AA_01', 'BB_02', 'CC_03', 'CC_03', 'CC_03', 'CC_03', 'DD_05', 'DD_05'],
                       'Time_since_A':[0, 134, 0, 7, 145, 289, 312, 500, 650]})
print(df)

# Intended output
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID_Code':['AA_01', 'AA_01', 'BB_02', 'CC_03', 'CC_03', 'CC_03', 'CC_03', 'DD_05', 'DD_05'],
                       'Time_since_A':[0, 134, 0, 7, 145, 289, 312, 500, 650],
                        'Timepoint':[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 'NA', 'NA']})
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) for Series with same size like original, so possible compare and for filtered groups use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter per groups:

```
mask = df.groupby('ID_Code')['Time_since_A'].transform('first') <= 10
df.loc[mask, 'Timepoint'] = df[mask].groupby('ID_Code').cumcount() + 1
print (df)
  ID_Code  Time_since_A  Timepoint
0   AA_01             0        1.0
1   AA_01           134        2.0
2   BB_02             0        1.0
3   CC_03             7        1.0
4   CC_03           145        2.0
5   CC_03           289        3.0
6   CC_03           312        4.0
7   DD_05           500        NaN
8   DD_05           650        NaN
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('ID_Code')['Time_since_A'].transform('first'))
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      7
4      7
5      7
6      7
7    500
8    500
Name: Time_since_A, dtype: int64
```